# Referenciar componentes da Activity

Tags: java, android

Pesquisei porém não encontrei resposta.

Eu preciso acessar um `TextView` que está presente na minha `Activity` dentro de uma Java Class que é independente da Java Class da própria `Activity`.

A forma que eu tentei foi criando uma referência: `public static TextView txtJogo;`, porém, está dando uma exception:

> "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views."

Como estou tentando:

```
CadastroAnuncioActivity.txtJogo.setText(anuncio.getTitulo());
```

Segue a classe onde preciso ter acesso ao `TextView`:

```
public class IGDBHelper {

    //  public JSONArray json = new JSONArray();

    // public void setJsonArray(JSONArray jsonArray){
    //    this.json = jsonArray;
    // }

    public void pesquisarJogo(String string) {
        IGDBWrapper igdbWrapper = new IGDBWrapper("c59880bb3fdc0b21e75c85b89745fd8d", Version.STANDARD, false);
        Parameters parameters = new Parameters().addSearch(string).addFields("id,name,summary,popularity,total_rating").addLimit("1");
        igdbWrapper.search(Endpoints.GAMES, parameters, new OnSuccessCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(@NotNull JSONArray jsonArray) {
                System.out.println(jsonArray + "anuncio");
                jsonToObj(jsonArray);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(@NotNull Exception e) {

            }
        });

    }

    public void jsonToObj(JSONArray resultadoDaPesquisa) {
        Anuncio anuncio = new Anuncio();
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < resultadoDaPesquisa.length(); i++) {
                jsonObject = resultadoDaPesquisa.getJSONObject(i);
                String id = jsonObject.getString("id");
                String nome = jsonObject.getString("name");
                String descricao = jsonObject.getString("summary");
                String popularidade = jsonObject.getString("popularity");
                //String rating = jsonObject.getString("rating");

                anuncio.setUid(id);
                anuncio.setTitulo(nome);
                anuncio.setDescricao(descricao);
                anuncio.setPopularidade(popularidade);
                //anuncio.setRating(rating);

                System.out.println(anuncio.toString());
                CadastroAnuncioActivity.txtJogo.setText(anuncio.getTitulo());
                CadastroAnuncioActivity.txtId.setText(anuncio.getUid());
                CadastroAnuncioActivity.txtDescricao.setText(anuncio.getDescricao());
                CadastroAnuncioActivity.txtPopularidade.setText(anuncio.getPopularidade());
                //CadastroAnuncioActivity.txtRating.setText(anuncio.getRating());
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Tem como vc colocar o código dessa Class ? Porque dependendo do que vc faz dentro dela, basta vc a partir da sua Activity chamar a class e colocar o seu retorno no setText do seu TextView

Comment: Não é uma boa pratica, o melhor caminho seria usar o ViewModel para fazer a lógica do JSON e um MutableLiveData do objeto que vai notificar a Activity e ai você da update nos campos de texto

Comment: Fazendo funcionar depois eu posso aperfeiçoar mas no momento, quero só fazer funcionar, independente da forma que vou usar pra isso

Answer (score 1):

Como o próprio erro diz, outra thread, além da main, está tentando alterar views - o que não é permitido.

A solução é sempre executar o código que altera as views na main thread.

Se estiver dentro da activity:

```
runOnUiThread(() -> {
  // Seu codigo
});
```

Ou, quando fora de uma activity:

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
handler.post(() -> {
  // Seu codigo
});
```

---

Para também solucionar de forma "simples" o problema de ter que criar um campo estático, sugiro refatorar o seu código da seguinte maneira.

Crie uma interface, que poderá ser usada para callbacks:

```
public interface Consumer<T> {

    void accept(T t);

}
```

E faça seus métodos chamarem um callback quando o objeto tiver sido convertido:

```
public void pesquisarJogo(String string, Consumer<Anuncio> callback) {
    ...
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(@NotNull JSONArray jsonArray) {
            System.out.println(jsonArray + "anuncio");
            jsonToObj(jsonArray, callback);
        }
    ...
}

public void jsonToObj(JSONArray resultadoDaPesquisa, Consumer<Anuncio> callback) {
    ...
    anuncio.setUid(id);
    anuncio.setTitulo(nome);
    anuncio.setDescricao(descricao);
    anuncio.setPopularidade(popularidade);
    callback.accept(anuncio);
}
```

Agora na sua Activity você terá acesso ao anúncio dentro do callback:

```
// Na activity, sem campos estáticos
igdbHelper.pesquisarJogo("hello", (anuncio) -> {
    runOnUiThread(() -> atualizarCampos(anuncio));
})

private void atualizarCampos(Anuncio anuncio) {
    txtJogo.setText(anuncio.getTitulo());
    txtId.setText(anuncio.getUid());
    txtDescricao.setText(anuncio.getDescricao());
    txtPopularidade.setText(anuncio.getPopularidade());
}
```